# IE6 Elements changing size on hover

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

1. View the following page in IE6: http://www.kickitback.com/Shop.aspx
2. Hover over the rows in the table
3. Notice how the rows change width and sometimes borders disappear

I've tried putting zoom:1 on various elements and setting widths and heights but so far it hasn't been successful. Any ideas?

Edit: I'm using javascript to apply a class to the rows on hover. My problem is due to some weird hover bug, not the absence of support for :hover.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember you can't do this with only css in ie6. You should use some JavaScript code.
[How to do it you can look here](http://snipplr.com/view/1912/internet-explorer-ie6-css-hover/).

Comment: That's not the problem. I am applying a class with javascript in order to do the hover effects.

Comment: why don't you use CSS hover properties ?